# Skip first element in orderBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have something default as first element like this:

```
var defaultType = {"name":"Select Type","typeId":"-1"};
$scope.selectedTypes.push(defaultType);
```

Then I am adding other elements like this:

```
var metadataObj = {'name':type.name, "typeId":type.typeId};
$scope.selectedTypes.push(metadataObj);
```

I want to sort these elements in ascending order by name. So I used:

```
data-ng-options="option.name for option in selectedTypes | orderBy:'name' track by option.typeId"
```

But I am still getting the first element in last.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$scope.selectedTypes.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.name > b.name ? 1 : a.name < b.name ? -1 : 0;
});
```

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 14,
  "colno": 48
}